# php password verification

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to create a online system wherein each user logs in with a unique id and password. I have implemented the code to verify the password but how do i redirect to a new(home) page after a successful password verification?

Comment: How is the password verified?

Answer (score 6):

You need to output a header to redirect them:

```
header('Location: newpage.php');
```

Keep in mind that you should verify your user is authenticated on every page, otherwise people can access the urls directly.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the home url is at home.php

```
header("Location: home.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

after you check that user is authenticated you should write this line

```
header('location: home.php');
```

by this line of code you will redirect to home.php page..

Answer (score 0):

As other guys said, you should use header() function, but you need to specify the full URL for Location, not only URI. Source: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html #14.30
Like so:

```
header('Location: http://site.com/home.php');
```

And make sure you not sending anything to output before header() call.

Comment: thats not true. You can use only filename or relative path also.

Comment: "You can" does not mean "you should". This works, but this is not guaranteed. See the RFC link. Some clients may not understand location without full URL and I've seen that.